# Cancel Jobs with JobManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, job-queue

I'm currently working on a project where uses JobManager. I add the jobs in the background this way.

`jobManager.addJobInBackground(new GetMessageBoard(page, jobId));`

I currently running into a problem the users jump from one tab to another before the job is finished. This causes the app to break. I want to know how I can cancel the jobs when the users switch to another view.

I see that the JobManager has the `cancelJobsInBackground()` function but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: What library is JobManager from?

Comment: com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:3.0.0